# Azure SSL binding work only with www. Not working for root domain

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-devops, dns, ssl-certificate

I have developed the website and hosted it on azure. Through the app service, I added SSL binding to both example.com and wwww.example.com.

htttps://www.example.com is working perfectly without any issues but htttps://example.com shows a below error for me.

> *Your connection is not private*

Refer to the attached pictures.

[image: Custom domain with verified status in azure here]

[image: Website showing no secure issue here]

[image: SSL bounded in azure here]

Answer (score 0):

For the error message, you could verify if the certificate is located in your local **Trusted Root Certification Authorities**. If not, you could move there.

[image]

The ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error can be caused by the following 3 reasons:

1. SSL certificate is self-signed.、
2. SSL certificate has expired.
3. SSL certificate is issued from non-trusted sources/certificate authority.

Sometimes, the corrupted Chrome cache can cause the issue, you could clear browsing data or disable Extensions and Plugins or update or reboot your Chrome. To fix it, you could look up [here](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/neterr-cert-authority-invalid/) for more details.